# socket IO client do not receive anything

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket io with node to manage an chat application

I can easily connect to my socket well  , however , when I connect from other other machine , the client do not recive anything .

in other machine , there is no antivirus and firewall disabled . ( I use google chrome and opera  and windows 7 )

something that is really interesting is that I can connect to socket with my mobile well !

when that machine connect to system , I can see this debug in console

```
 info  - socket.io started
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0
   debug - client authorized for 
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   **debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"ready","args":[{"msg":"hi"}]}**
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0?t=1374596975155
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/gu63jD6tYNPCf7JO72U0?t=1374596985158&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - clearing poll timeout
```

I use this to connect to my site :

**var socket = io.connect('192.168.1.101:900');**

the machine do not get 404 not found , or error , just the methods did not fire...

as you can see , the client should receive *ready* , but it do not get , where is the problem ?

the server source :

```
var express = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'),
        app = express()
        , http = require('http')
        , server = http.createServer(app)
        , io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

// listen for new web clients:
server.listen(900, function() {
    //console.log(this);
});


// routing
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('It works');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.emit('ready', {msg: 'hi'});
}
```

Client

```
    var socket = io.connect('192.168.1.101:900');
    console.log('connecting');

    socket.on('error', function(data) {
        console.log(data || 'error');
    });

    socket.on('connect_failed', function(data) {
        console.log(data || 'connect_failed');
    });

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function() {

        alert('work');
    });

    socket.on('ready', function() {

        alert('work');
    });
```

Comment: Could you post browser version of failing client?

Comment: Show the relevant code at node.js server and client.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs  : source code added , please take a look ...

Comment: What does console show in the browser.

Comment: it show connecting , after 60-70 sec , it show connect_failed , even after  io.connect() , I got the result at server side ...